# Is there any way to set a background colour to the full column for Saturday and Sunday in 'React Full Calendar'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using '**react full calendar**' for my react application. I want to change the **background color** for the full column for **Saturday and Sunday**. How can I achieve this?

const {withHtml} = this.state;

```
    return (

        <div className="calendar-wrapper ">

            <BigCalendar
                selectable
                events={events}
                views={""}
                onSelectSlot={event => this.onSelectSlot() }
                defaultDate={new Date()}

            />

                <SweetAlert
                    show={withHtml}
                    btnSize="sm"
                    title={<span>HTML <small>Title</small>!</span>}
                    onConfirm={() => this.onConfirm('withHtml')}>
                    <span>A custom <span style={{color: '#642aff'}}>html</span> message.</span>
                </SweetAlert>


        </div>




    );
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and we'll help you from there.

Comment: Thank you. Found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dayPropGetter` property to customize it

Here is how your function should looks like

```
const customDayPropGetter = (date: Date) => {
  if (date.getDate() === 7 || date.getDate() === 6)
    return {
      className: 'special-day',
      style: {
        border: 'solid 3px ' + (date.getDate() === 7 ? '#faa' : '#afa'),
      },
    };
  else return {};
};
```

and assign function like this

```
 dayPropGetter={customDayPropGetter}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7jqzpp50q1)

[source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-big-calendar/react-big-calendar-tests.tsx#L175)

Comment: Does anyone know how to change the text color(date number) inside a cell?